# Класс обработчик

Tags: c#, wpf, api, mvvm

Работаю с VK Api для общего развития, понимания Api в целом.И все графические составляющие (создание моделей для сообщений и т.д.) делаются прямо в методах, отправляющих запрос с последующим получением ответа.

Стоит ли делать отдельный класс, отвечающий за создание моделей или лучше оставить это за методами, выполняющими запрос? Будет ли это эффективнее/нет?

Comment: необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? Есть класс, отвечающий за запросы насчёт сообщений(Messages).Методы в нём называются аналогично тем запросам, которые они выполняют к самой АПИ.Например, getHistory.Внутри метода, HttpRequest из xNet, делает запрос и получает ответ, а Newtonsoft.json выполняет парсинг ответа.Затем в этом же методе прописан цикл, создающий модели сообщений для usercontrol`ов и в конце передаёт сформированную коллекцию в нужный класс, отвечающий за VM для страницы чата.В последствии эта коллекция биндится к itemscontrol с datatemplate в виде usercontrol.

Comment: Это из разряда "нужен мне код портянка или нет". Сами как думаете, что удобней, когда все намешано в одном методе и в итоге у вас 1 класс с 10000++ строк кода, или разбито на объекты, классы, которые имеют свои локальные методы управления и в итоге вы имеете 30 классов с 100++ срок кода каждый?

Comment: Понятное дело, что код порятнка никому не нужен.Меня больше интересует эффективность данного подхода.Эффективность того, что в цепочке от получения до вывода появляется класс-посредник.Разница минимальна, либо ощутима, это хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: Это экономия на спичках.

Comment: Каждый метод желательно, чтобы делал что то одно. Если метод запрашивает данные с сервиса - пусть он это и делает. Если метод для создания модели - желательно, чтобы он только модели создавал и больше ничего, не делал. То же с классами. Если у вас класс для запросов к VK.API, то пусть он только этим и занимается, больше ничем. Подробней [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Comment: Всех благодарю за ответы